# wp auto insert tag in posts

Tags: wordpress, tags, seo

when I edit a post in wp sometimes I don't assign a tag , is it a good Idea to auto insert a tag like the category name or my site name instead of no tag at all?
and if its better to input a tag then I need help writing a function that check if the post has no tag then it will insert lets say my sitename.

all what I have is

wp_set_post_tags( 42, 'mepanorama', true );

but this will work only on specific post and does not check if there is a tag already.

Comment: This isn't a question, per se. What tags you set depends on why you might want tags set in the first place. Not having any tags is perfectly valid for many scenarios.

Comment: I thought maybe if my site name appears on many post have some effect on SEO. - or not.

Answer (score 2):

This will return the number of tags:

```
count(wp_get_post_terms($post_id, 'post_tag', array("fields" => "names")));
```

I made a plugin that adds tags to posts automatically, it is called [Automatic Post Tagger](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/automatic-post-tagger). Check it out, it might be useful for you. :)

Comment: Thanks Devtard , I will try it but I like to avoid plugins when I can.

Comment: too bad , non-Latin alphabets like Arabic or Chinese aren't supported , my site is arabic